React Native Camera - I am getting error "Error: tag must be a valid string" when I use start recording and stop recording in vision camera
React Native - Vision camera
I am facing 1 issue in using camera. While recording video I click on start Recording and on stop recording it gives error message "Error: tag must be a valid string" although it works fine on 2nd attempt.
These are the functions I am using -
Always 1st time I was able to catch this as exception and show "Errr!! Unfortunately there is problem in recording, Please reshoot the video"
`async function StartRecodingHandler() {
camera.current.startRecording({
flash: 'off',
audio: 'true',
onRecordingFinished: (video) => setvideopath(video.path),
onRecordingError: (error) => console.error(error, 'videoerror')   
})
setrecordingstatus("Recording Started and In Progress")
}

async function stopRecodingHandler() {
await camera.current.stopRecording()
setrecordingstatus("Recording Completed")
// Copy the file to Gallery //
try 
{ await CameraRoll.saveAsset(videopath, 
{
type:'video',
})
Alert.alert('Video Recorded Successfull'); 
}
catch(e)
{
var emsg = e
console.log(emsg=="Error: tag must be a valid string")
if(emsg=="Error: tag must be a valid string")
{  
Alert.alert('Errr!! Unfortunately there is problem in recording, Please reshoot the video'); 
setrecordingstatus("Error in recording !! Please Retry")
}
else
Alert.alert('Error came '+e)
}  

}`


